# How to change authentication from FBA to Active Directory?

Tags: 2010, active-directory, forms-authentication

Is there a way to change authentication from FBA to Active Directory?
Since I am on FBA (claims based), I am unable to use many features of SP2010 like MySites etc.

I would appreciate if someone can help me out on this! Any recommendation for a third party app would also be great!

Comment: Do you want to use AD *in addtion* to FBA or *instead* of FBA?

Comment: I want AD instead of FBA. On second thought is 'Only' AD better?

Comment: Please take care of the fact that it's hard to map FBA users to AD users. Documents/sites/lists that have ownership by a FBA user, will get lost and not replaced by it's corresponding AD user!

Comment: @Bas Does any third party app make the mapping simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 you can use mutliple authentication methods per zone, so you can simply enable Windows authentication in addition to forms. See this blog on [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brporter/archive/2010/05/10/temp.aspx).

Comment: I want MySites working on my SP2010 site - It would be very nice of you if you can suggest the approach considering that I am on FBA (claims-based) now & what to do next.

Comment: If you mean, how to change authentication mode on existing site - Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications (select web app) -> Authentication Providers (in ribbon) -> Default (zone) -> Scroll down to Claims Authentication Types and check on the Enable Windows Authentication checkbox.

Comment: Will 'MySites' get enabled if I follow your method?

Comment: Configuring MySites is a whole other question.